# fetch data with async pipe when view is ready

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a basic table component. The user is able to reload and filter the data.
For those two actions I use Subjects.

```
private fetchFromServer$ = new Subject<void>();
private filter$ = new Subject<void>();
```

The data fetch will then be switched into an observable:

```
private externalData$ = this.fetchFromServer$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.loadFromServer())
);
```

Afterwards the observable (with the external data) will be combined with the filter-subject, like this:

```
data$ = combineLatest([this.externalData$, this.filter$]).pipe(
  switchMap(([externalData]) => this.search(externalData))
);
```

here is the basic view:

```
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  {{data |json}}
</div>

<button (click)="reload()">reload</button>
<button (click)="filter()">filter</button>
```

But this implementation has some drawbacks yet:

The table won't be displayed initially. combineLatest needs at least one emit of externalData$ and filter$. If both buttons "reload" and "filter" gets clicked, the table data will be displayed.
But that's not the problem, because I want to display the table initially and as a result I want to call

```
fetchFromServer$.next()
filter$.next();
```

on the correct position.

But exactly here is my problem. Where to call those two lines?
If I put them in the ngOnInit()-method, the data won't be shown. I guess, because the async pipe subscribes to it later.

Or should the Observable be a hot observable with replaying the last emit? But I have no clue how to do that and furthermore it must be unsubscribed in the ngOnDestroy()-method?

Should it be placed into the ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook? Then it works, but I get he famous "Expression has changed after it was checked" error.

Here is the sample project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sl3kku

Comment: Your analysis looks good. Since you use Subjects, when the pipe subscribes, it may be too late. So what about replacings Subject with BehaviorSubject ? BehaviorSubject automatically gives the last received event whenever someone subscribes.

Comment: can't you add additional flag, eg: loaded$ = new BehaviorSubject(false); and put a value in the .combineLatest pipe you could toggle it loaded$.next(true) and use that to control if should be visible in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Subject to emit directly, you should use `BehaviorSubject` that will take a default value as an argument (`null` in your case) and will emit it as soon as we subscribe to it.

Also to filter your data locally, it would be simpler to use an [Angular Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes), I made a fork of your Stack Blitz with an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnsskv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you. I'm using --strictNullChecks and gets the following compiler error: "Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'." Should I use "new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined)" because that seems to work?

Comment: That would be the same yes.

Comment: Actually is most cases, your Subject type will be what you want to return, i.e. `any[]`, in this case you would be able to use `[]` as a default value which makes more sense.

Comment: Ok I understand. in this case I don't need any return value so we are good to use type <void> and return undefined.